# How to prevent spotlight from searching external hard drives

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, external-hard-drive, usb-storage, spotlight

I have an external hard drive connected to my Macbook Pro that I always leave on. When I use spotlight to search for something, it always searches this drive. I don't want it to do this because usually the drive is in standby mode, so it takes a while to power up when I use spotlight to find something, and usually what I'm trying to find isn't on that hard drive. How can I prevent spotlight from searching this drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How disable mac snow leopard creating .Spotlight-V100 and .Trash folders in USB Flash Drivers?](http://superuser.com/questions/89556/how-disable-mac-snow-leopard-creating-spotlight-v100-and-trash-folders-in-usb)

Answer (score 6):

System Prefs --> Spotlight --> Privacy.

Add the drive(s) you want to exclude.

**UPDATE:**

For a scripting approach try this: [Disabling Spotlight in OS X Leopard for the removable drives](http://myhowto.org/mac-os-x/52-disabling-spotlight-in-os-x-leopard-for-the-removable-drives/)

Should work for Snow Leopard too.

Comment: The only drawback is that if you unmount the drive you will have to re-add it again in the future.

Comment: No that's not correct.  If you add it to the privacy pane, that computer (and others) will ignore it for spotlight in the future.  The spotlight pane writes a .<something> file to the root of the drive, which other systems will recognize.  At least that's the way it works in OS 10.6 and I believe in 10.5...

Comment: @Benjamin Schollnick - You mean the hidden .Spotlight-V100 folder? You are correct but at the time of writing that comment I had not fully researched the behaviour of Spotlight indexing.

Comment: I was thinking of the .metadata_never_index  file...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't want Spotlight to index the drive either, create a file,

> .metadata_never_index

on the root of the drive.  It will no longer get indexed, and, no index, no search.  From [this tip from Mac OS-X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060814124808745).